# module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_nccl_version' in Window11, GeForce RTX 3070

Tags: pytorch, gpu

My settings are:

```
GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU
Window 11
Fresh virtual env with conda
```

I installed torch and cuda with this command:

```
pip install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Then checked the setup with the following command,

```
import torch

print("torch.__version__", torch.__version__)
print("torch.version.cuda", torch.version.cuda)
print("torch.__config__", torch.__config__.show())
print("torch.cuda.device_count", torch.cuda.device_count())  # Print the number of CUDA devices
```

Results:

```
torch.__version__ 1.9.0+cu111
torch.version.cuda 11.1
torch.__config__ PyTorch built with:
  - C++ Version: 199711
  - MSVC 192829337
  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2020.0.2 Product Build 20200624 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v2.1.2 (Git Hash 98be7e8afa711dc9b66c8ff3504129cb82013cdb)
  - OpenMP 2019
  - CPU capability usage: AVX2
  - CUDA Runtime 11.1
  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_80,code=sm_80;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=compute_37
  - CuDNN 8.0.5
  - Magma 2.5.4
  - Build settings: BLAS_INFO=mkl, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CUDA_VERSION=11.1, CUDNN_VERSION=8.0.5, CXX_COMPILER=C:/w/b/windows/tmp_bin/sccache-cl.exe, CXX_FLAGS=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /w /bigobj -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -openmp:experimental -IC:/w/b/windows/mkl/include -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DLIBKINETO_NOCUPTI -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE, LAPACK_INFO=mkl, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, TORCH_VERSION=1.9.0, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_CUDNN=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=OFF, USE_NNPACK=OFF, USE_OPENMP=ON, 

torch.cuda.device_count 1
```

print(torch.cuda.nccl.version())

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 print(torch.cuda.nccl.version())

File c:\Users\loren\miniconda3\envs\nlp_cuda_phi2_1\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\nccl.py:35, in version()
     34 def version():
---> 35     return torch._C._nccl_version()

AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_nccl_version'
```

Is there any solution for that?
I googled alot, and seems people are suggesting torch==1.9.0, but my version is torch==1.9.0 already.